# issue with WebClient DownloadString

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, download, webclient, downloadstring

issue with WebClient DownloadString :

My Code ~

```
WebClient Wc = new WebClient();
string myUrl = "http://www.google.com";
string myStr = string.Empty;
myStr = Wc.DownloadString(myUrl);
Console.Write(myStr);
```

**Error : 
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

Note :

Internet is working properly then what can be the issue with this ?

Comment: Even this doesnt seem to work : 
NetworkCredential Nc = new NetworkCredential("username","password","domain");
Wc.Credentials = Nc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may need to specify some proxy settings. Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to look at the difference between what happens in your test app and what happens in a browser. I expect that both are going to a proxy, but that the browser request has proxy authentication and the `WebClient` one doesn't.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Can you please tell me where changes are expected in above code for specifying "proxy settings".As I have no idea about proxy usage in WebClient class.

Comment: @Pratik: Verify that it's the case first. Then use the WebClient.Proxy property if necessary.

Comment: @Jon: This is also not working 
//WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://wireshark.org",true);
//proxyObject.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
//Wc.Proxy = proxyObject;

Comment: Even this doesnt seem to work : NetworkCredential Nc = new NetworkCredential("username","password","domain"); Wc.Credentials = Nc;

Comment: @Pratik: I wasn't suggesting using wireshark.org as a proxy - it's a *tool* to monitor network traffic. You can see exactly what's happening on the wire using it.

Comment: @Jon: Since I don't have admin rights that wont work.(I mean tool installion for monitoring networking).Can I do any changes in my code to achive the functionality, I am opting for

Comment: @Pratik: You can't install that tool *on your development machine*? I'm sure you can make some changes to the code to fix it, but we don't know *what* changes are required until we know more about what's going on.